# URL rewriting with regular expressions

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to extract 2 pieces of information from the URL below, "events/festivals" and "sandiego.storeboard.com".

How can I do that with a regular expression?

```
http://sandiego.storeboard.com/classifieds/events/festivals
```

I need this information for a URL rewrite in IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^http://([^/]*)/classifieds/([^/]*/[^/]*)/
```

The `[^/]` snippet means "everything which is **not** a `/`"

Answer (score 0):

It's not the fastest solution but it works:

```
(.*?)/classifieds/(.*)
```

Comment: Might want to use .*? for the first capture to minimize backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

The following C# code will retrun the two strings that you requested.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GroupCollection result = GetResult("http://sandiego.storeboard.com/classifieds/events/festivals");
        Console.Write(result[1] + " " + result[2]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static GroupCollection GetResult(string url)
    {
        string reg = @".*?(\w+\.\w+\.com).*?(events\/festivals)";
        return Regex.Match(url, reg).Groups;
    }
}
```